# write applescript click OK button to pop-ups

Tags: applescript

I'm having trouble writing an apple script that can click "OK" buttons.  I play online poker games and I have to click a few "OK" buttons to register a tournament.  I'd like to have the script to click whenever there is an "OK" button appear on screen. So when I click "register" button, a pop up says something like "are you sure you want to register in this tournament?", I click "OK", and than another popup says "You are now registered", than than I have to click "OK", than another popup says "tournament will start in a moment", another "OK" button clicked.

Comment: Joe, this is a programming site. We talk about strategy for accomplishing task and we help with code. Do you have either of those things? How do you propose to solve your problem? Have you tried anything?

Comment: See UI for the poker client http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=29pqgc8&s=6 and my applescript below.


activate application "RPM Poker"

tell application "System Events"

 tell process "RPM Poker"


  click button "Register"
  click button "OK" of window "Tournament Registration Success"
 end tell
end tell

Comment: I'm getting an error "System Events got an error: Can’t get button "Register" of process "RPM Poker".

Answer (score 0):

OK Joe, I see your code in the comments of your question. Buttons are usually part of a window or sheet and you don't have either of those as part of your "click button Register" line of code. Funny that you do have it as part of the next line though. Anyway, try this and see if "Register" is one of the name of the buttons in the front window. If so then you just need to add "of window 1" to that line of code. If not then something else is wrong.

```
activate application "RPM Poker"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "RPM Poker"
        return title of buttons of window 1 -- try "name" or "description" instead of "title" if it doesn't work
    end tell
end tell
```

From looking at your picture I doubt "click button anything" will work because that's a web page and not a normal cocoa window. You may have to use some sort of javascript code to click things on a web page. Anyway, try the script and see if it sees the button.